Prefab not rendering in unity after changing the color
I'm trying to make a tile system, and I have a function that changes the color of every other tile to make a checkerboard pattern. However, after the color is changed from white (the default) to any other color, it doesn't show up.

Grid Manager Script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int width , height;

    [SerializeField] private Tile tilePrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateGrid();
    }

    void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var spawnedTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab , new Vector3(x , y) , Quaternion.identity);
                spawnedTile.name = $"Tile {x} {y}";

                var isOffset = (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 != 0) || (x % 2 != 0 && y % 2 == 0);
                spawnedTile.Init(isOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}

Tile Script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Color baseColor , offsetColor;
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer renderer;

    public void Init(bool isOffset)
    {
        if (isOffset)
        {
            renderer.color = offsetColor;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer.color = baseColor;
        }
    }
}

I've tried changing the color manually in the editor without calling the "Init" function, and that works fine.

alpha is 0 in the color.  it would be nice if they default the alpha to 1, this problem is super common.


I think the alpha is still 0, Change it to 255..
